# Asking a question that *must* have been asked before but I can't find

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I have a question I'd like to pose on the Stack Overflow site, but I'm sure it's been asked before - I've not seen it before, but it's so fundamentally useful to the specific thing I'm doing (that other people also do) that I can't believe I'm the first to ask it. The problem is I can't find the question for love nor money.

Is there a best practice for asking a question such as this?

(For reference my question is: how to automatically redirect all Python calls to an [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) virtual environment in Linux). The issue with finding the specific question may be the phrasing I use in the search (I also do a SE search via Google to no avail).

Comment: There's a *chance* that that's considered OS specific enough to be on another site. Maybe Super User. I think there may actually be a Linux site. Don't use the internal search though. It's terrible at fuzzy searches.

Comment: It sounds like you've done your due diligence.  Worst case, someone with an expertise in the area knows of a duplicate and your question becomes a good signpost.

Comment: Don't forget to include what you searched for. So instead of *I searched everywhere* mention *I searched for "Python anaconda VM" and it did return X but I need Y*. The latter will give potential answerers a better starting point and/or might spot that you use the wrong technical terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem is I can't find the question for love nor money.

And the solution might be to ask it.

As for the appropriate site - it sounds like a good "How do I do foo" question with practical considerations

While I'm obviously biased towards Super User - I half suspect that Unix and Linux would be a better site.

Even if close as dupe, a *well asked* question still has value.

Comment: I think it would be appropriate on Stack Overflow -- if it has the correct tags.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a question I'd like to pose on the Stack Overflow site, ... my question is: how to automatically redirect all Python calls to an Anaconda virtual environment in Linux.

Always check carefully.

If you can't find it in a period of time **much longer** than the **30 seconds** it took me to find: "[How can I execute Python scripts using Anaconda's version of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27005561/3648282)" (Windows) ***or*** "[How do I run .py files by double clicking if I have Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53109075/3648282)" (Linux) then it's reasonable to ask. It took much longer to write this than to find what appears to be two similar questions.

Accept that if it's a duplicate question (or even a non-duplicate question, with the answer you need) that your question may be closed. Be satisfied that you have your answer (***if*** the question was answered) and that there's another road leading future travelers.

There are already answers here on our main Meta recommending techniques to improve the chances of obtaining an answer. There are also articles elsewhere recommending how to use search tools effectively.

We all have times were the answer lies before us and we can't see it, much as we have occasions were the answers we receive have shortcomings and need some polishing; that's a good occasion to write your own *better* answer and help the people whom come across the same problem in the future.